# How to convert a list of 70 names in rows so that they have quotation marks " " and seperated by comma?

Tags: python, r, terminal, converters, bioconductor

how to make a convertion of say this list of items from:

```
qwe
wer
qwert
```

to:

```
"qwe", "wer", "qwert"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What format is the original list of names in? a .txt?

Comment: Are you reading in this list from a file or is it In your R environment?

Comment: Where is your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is it a dataframe? df['names'].tolist()

Comment: With R or Python?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @chemicalwill - my list of names are in a text file. I do not know how to do it from either terminal as I am not a hardcore bioinfomartics person. The list has about 70 names

Comment: @Elle - I am reading this list from R environment, but I have access to Ubuntu (windows).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - its on R

Comment: @RonakShah - I want to use it for ploting graphs with some of these names for the DEP package (Bioconductor) I am using.

Comment: @Wonka - I wouldlike to know the code I need to use to execute this function. I honestly do not know. I must say, I am a novice programmer, in case my question may seem elementary in general.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said they're in a .txt file (Python3):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    names = [f'"{line.strip()}"' for line in file.readlines()]

print(', '.join(names))
```

Comment: @user13480343 if this solves your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: it worked, thank you, I don`t know how to mark it as answer though.

Comment: @user13480343 there’s a clickable check mark to the left of my answer, under the vote arrows

Answer (score 0):

Items=['qwe','wer','qwert']

for word in Items:
print(word)

print()

for word in range(len(Items)):
print('"' + Items[word], end= '", ')

Comment: thank you very much. However, suppose I have a list in a text file, with 70 names, how to do that?

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You said your list of names is in a text file, so:

```
x <- read.table('filename')
```

That'll import it as a dataframe and to convert it to a vector you can just do:

```
nms <- x$V1
```

Where V1 is the name of the header. If your list of names has no header it'll most likely be V1, whereas if it does have a header you should add `header = TRUE` to your read.table() function and then use that, like `x$header`

---

Or to read it straight in as a character vector you can use:

```
x <- scan(filename, character())
```